# problem with django url dispatcher , unable to resolve the url

Tags: python, django, url, dispatcher

i got latest django installed and working through hello world tutorial

i got problem with getting url dispatcher working

i got configured as follow
in django_web/urls.py i got

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('TEST1', include('newpage.urls')),
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in newpage/urls.py i got

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name='index'),
        path('TEST' ,views.index2, name='cokolwiek'),
        ]
```

if i hit
*localhost:8000/TEST1* - works fine

if i hit
*localhost:8000/TEST1/TEST* - does not work i got followin message

> ```
> Using the URLconf defined in django_web.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> TEST1 [name='index']
> TEST1 TEST [name='cokolwiek']
> The current path, TEST1/TEST, didn't match any of these.
> ```

how the hell is that not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not use a slash, hence the path is `localhost:8000/TEST1TEST`. But likely you do not want that. You likely want to add a slash after the `TEST1`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('TEST1/', include('newpage.urls')),
]
```

this is also the reason why `admin/` is used. Django will normally first try the patterns, and if that did not resolve anything try to append a slash and tries the paths again. This is the effect of the [**`APPEND_SLASH`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#append-slash). But this is only done at the end of the *full* path. So it does not mean it adds a slash at the patterns.

Comment: i knew its some trivial typo, thanks indeed thats the case , its kind of not intuitive that you have to add that slash

Comment: @Wkordos: well sometimes it might be *wanted* to not have a slash between the `TEST1` and `TEST` :). But I agree it is not very common.

Answer (score 0):

under urls.py
add:
`path(' ', include('newpage.urls'))`,

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(" ",view.page,name="homepage.urls"),
    #path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

#In the main app open views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```

#Under create views here type:

```
def homepage(request)
```